# componentWillUnmount() being called on mounting - React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to remove this Warning :

Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Here is my React.js code :

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      firstLogin: null
    };

}

componentWillMount() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

       if (user) {
         firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).limitToFirst(1).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      this.setState({firstLogin: snapshot.val().infos.firstLogin});
        });
       });
      } 
      else {
        this.setState({firstLogin: null});
      }
    });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.setState({firstLogin: null});
}
```

When I try to console.log the componentWillUnmount() function :

```
componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("component unmount");
    this.setState({firstLogin: null});
}
```

I realize that the function is called as soon as the component is mounting...
So I have this warning.

Could you help me ?

Thanks

**--- EDIT---**

I removed componentWillUnmount but the warning is still here.

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      firstLogin: null
    };

}

componentWillMount() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

       if (user) {
         firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).limitToFirst(1).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      this.setState({firstLogin: snapshot.val().infos.firstLogin});
        });
       });
      } 
      else {
        this.setState({firstLogin: null});
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your parent component is unmounting it. Also don't set state in unmount

Comment: mounting/unmounting depends on how component appears in parent's component. having `key` changed or parent component unmounted will also unmount all the children

Comment: thanks, but added the componentwillunmount as the warning told me to do that. That's why I tried. I think it come from the setState in the componentwillmount, don't know how to clear it...

Comment: The warning told to cancel subscriptions that result in late `setState` call, not to add `setState` to componentWillUnmount.

Comment: I did it. Removed the ComponentWillUnmount. But same warning..

Comment: You didn't cancel subscriptions in componentWillUnmount, otherwise you wouldn't get this warning.

Comment: all right, but, how can I do it ?

Comment: There's no clean way for how you're using Firebase, existing answer explains how it can be done. A cleaner way is to switch to RxJS and RxFire. A great thing about observable subscriptions is that they can be cancelled from a single point.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call componentDidMount() instead of componentWillMount()

Comment: Do you really need to call setState() in the lifecycle method componentWillUnmount() ?

Comment: nope, I just did it because of the warning. I removed ComponentWillUnmount, but the warning is still there

Answer (score 0):

You should keep a variable to indicate the component is still mounted.

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      firstLogin: null
    };
    this._isMounted = false;
}

componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._isMounted = false;
}

componentWillMount() {

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

       if (this._isMounted && user) {
         firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).limitToFirst(1).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      this.setState({firstLogin: snapshot.val().infos.firstLogin});
        });
       });
      } 
      else if (this._isMounted){
        this.setState({firstLogin: null});
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's better to move it to didMount.